# Vuforia + Unity dynamic 3d models and triggers

Tags: unity-game-engine, cross-platform, augmented-reality, vuforia

I want to build a cross-platform mobile app that can identify QR-codes and will render a 3d model on it using AR.

I found that Unity in combination with Vuforia will do the trick on the AR part, but is it possible here to download and use 3D models dynamically?

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend more of a Vuforia specific forum, like https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-extension-technical-discussion/load-3d-model-through-cloud

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're looking for is called [AssetBundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) be aware that downloading a large model (+texture) at run time can be heavy and will highly depend on the internet connection of the device.

Hope this helps.